# QR code on my report is sometimes showing as error

Tags: out-of-memory, qr-code, rdlc, gdi+, image-rendering

I am generating a report, the report contains all the data fetched from the DB and a QR code should be shown at the bottom of the page. But sometimes the QR code is not showing, and an image with X is shown, whereas all my data is fetched properly.

I suspect that the image render is not happening properly.

I can see 2 exceptions during the issue time.

1. a generic error occurred in GDI+
2. out of memory exception.

Kindly help me in troubleshooting this

I'm unable to replicate this issue on my local machine. Also in production this issue is intermittent. I have to restart my service which resolves this issue.

Comment: *"But sometimes the QR code is not showing, and an image with X is shown, whereas all my data is fetched properly."* - how does the QR code being generated? please kindly provide us with [mcve] to work with.

Comment: Is your link a `URL` or `byte[]` data in database?